# Error when using the apply function on a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, norm

I'm trying to use apply to use the L1 norm on each column of a matrix in R. If we have a matrix

```
X=matrix(data=rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
```

Then when I run

```
apply(X,2,function(x) norm(x,type="1"))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in base::norm(x, type, ...) : 'A' must be a numeric matrix
```

I've found that this is because when we index X, we lose the matrix type. For example, running

```
norm(X[,1],type="1")
```

we get the same error. Hence, I've run

```
  old <- `[`
`[` <- function(...) { old(..., drop=FALSE) }
```

To stop the matrix type being dropped when we subset X. Now, this works

```
norm(X[,1],type="1")
```

But I still get the same error for

```
apply(X,2,function(x) norm(x,type="1"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `apply(X, 2, function(x) norm(matrix(x, ncol = 1), type = "1")`, but you could also just do `colSums(abs(X))`--there's not much point in using `norm` here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that `apply(X, 2, ...)` is producing "vector"s like below, which are not the `matrix` format as `norm` requested

```
> set.seed(1)

> X <- matrix(data = rnorm(100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

> apply(X, 2, str)
 num [1:10] -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 ...
 num [1:10] 1.512 0.39 -0.621 -2.215 1.125 ...
 num [1:10] 0.919 0.7821 0.0746 -1.9894 0.6198 ...
 num [1:10] 1.3587 -0.1028 0.3877 -0.0538 -1.3771 ...
 num [1:10] -0.165 -0.253 0.697 0.557 -0.689 ...
 num [1:10] 0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 num [1:10] 2.4016 -0.0392 0.6897 0.028 -0.7433 ...
 num [1:10] 0.476 -0.71 0.611 -0.934 -1.254 ...
 num [1:10] -0.569 -0.135 1.178 -1.524 0.594 ...
 num [1:10] -0.543 1.208 1.16 0.7 1.587 ...
NULL
```

---

A quick fix might be using `as.matrix` or `t()`, e.g.,

```
> apply(X, 2, function(x) str(as.matrix(x)))
 num [1:10, 1] -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 ...
 num [1:10, 1] 1.512 0.39 -0.621 -2.215 1.125 ...
 num [1:10, 1] 0.919 0.7821 0.0746 -1.9894 0.6198 ...
 num [1:10, 1] 1.3587 -0.1028 0.3877 -0.0538 -1.3771 ...
 num [1:10, 1] -0.165 -0.253 0.697 0.557 -0.689 ...
 num [1:10, 1] 0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 num [1:10, 1] 2.4016 -0.0392 0.6897 0.028 -0.7433 ...
 num [1:10, 1] 0.476 -0.71 0.611 -0.934 -1.254 ...
 num [1:10, 1] -0.569 -0.135 1.178 -1.524 0.594 ...
 num [1:10, 1] -0.543 1.208 1.16 0.7 1.587 ...
NULL

> apply(X, 2, function(x) str(t(x)))
 num [1, 1:10] -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 ...
 num [1, 1:10] 1.512 0.39 -0.621 -2.215 1.125 ...
 num [1, 1:10] 0.919 0.7821 0.0746 -1.9894 0.6198 ...
 num [1, 1:10] 1.3587 -0.1028 0.3877 -0.0538 -1.3771 ...
 num [1, 1:10] -0.165 -0.253 0.697 0.557 -0.689 ...
 num [1, 1:10] 0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 num [1, 1:10] 2.4016 -0.0392 0.6897 0.028 -0.7433 ...
 num [1, 1:10] 0.476 -0.71 0.611 -0.934 -1.254 ...
 num [1, 1:10] -0.569 -0.135 1.178 -1.524 0.594 ...
 num [1, 1:10] -0.543 1.208 1.16 0.7 1.587 ...
NULL
```

such that

```
> apply(X, 2, function(x) norm(as.matrix(x), type = "1"))
 [1] 6.497906 8.282578 6.963624 6.011803 5.194332 8.010169 9.687043 5.383619
 [9] 6.336799 9.304195
```

or (be careful, we use `type = "I"` here)

```
> apply(X, 2, function(x) norm(t(x), type = "I"))
 [1] 6.497906 8.282578 6.963624 6.011803 5.194332 8.010169 9.687043 5.383619
 [9] 6.336799 9.304195
```

---

Cross-check with `colSums(abs(X))` (as mentioned by [Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74182583/12158757))

```
> colSums(abs(X))
 [1] 6.497906 8.282578 6.963624 6.011803 5.194332 8.010169 9.687043 5.383619
 [9] 6.336799 9.304195
```

Comment: It's worth calling out that `t()` will produce row vectors, not column vectors, hence your changing the norm `type` from OP's `"1"` to `"I"`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, you got it. I should use `as.matrix` if don't want to replace `1` by `I`.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want OP (or anyone else) seeing `t()` and not also noticing the `"1"` to `"I"` change.